# Changing URL of REST API

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, rest

I am currently using the WordPress REST API to provide data to an app.  All requests are currently sent to http://www.currentwebsite.com/wp-json/.... but the current website is going to be split, with much of the content going on to a new website with a different URL.

It makes more sense content wise to move the API data to the new website but this means the URL being used will change.

Is there a way to redirect requests to http://www.currentwebsite.com/wp-json/.... to go to http://www.newwebsite.com/wp-json/....?  I can redirect all requests to the new website but I only need to API requests to be redirected as there will still be a full website at http://www.currentwebsite.com.

Many Thanks

Comment: you can send by curl post

Comment: what will be in the futur on the URL http://www.currentwebsite.com/... ?

Comment: Half of the pages on the current website. While half will be moved to the new website